# What was the profession 芸者 (female entertainer) called in Britain?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, phrase-requests

I am looking for an indigenous English word for women who entertained guests at social gatherings in Britain. To put it simply, I am looking for an English analogue of geisha.

Comment: If you're talking about dancers and singers, they were called *dancers* and *singers*.

Comment: I'm not sure Britain had an analogous geisha culture.

Comment: @PeterShor : It is more than just dancing and singing.

Comment: In ***Japan,*** the female entertainers called geisha did more than just dancing and singing. (And some of the English entertainers called dancers and singers did more than dancing and singing, too.)

Comment: @PeterShor : What was the name for the British female entertainers who did more than just dancing and singing?

Comment: *Hostess*, perhaps? But *entertaining guests* refers to providing food and drink.

Comment: Imagine a high-class social gathering organized by a king or a prince. Many men are present. And present are also women whose profession is to entertain guests - by talking with them, dancing, singing, and so on. What were such women called in Britain?

Comment: Were there such women in Britain? If there were, they were called *singers*. And they did not spend years learning how to talk with guests.

Comment: I would call them *hostesses*, and the term *hostess bar* is quite commonly used in some parts of the world... but in the UK I am not sure there is any such profession. *Courtesan* is not a word you can use with a straight face.

Comment: I think the standard "translation" was ***comfort women***. But it's not a "profession" that's generally recognised in most Anglophone countries as being distinct from ***prostitute***, and most terms for anything close would probably be essentially "euphemisms".

Comment: Are you looking for its modern-day equivalent or its 18th/19th/20th century counterpart (euphemism)?

Comment: @Mari-LouA : My assumption was that there were professional female entertainers in Britain who entertained guests at social gatherings by talking, singing, dancing, etc., similar to what geishas did in Japan. And I wanted to  know what those British women were called at that time. But the comments suggest that there was no such profession in Britain.

Comment: Your question uses the past tense. What time period are you looking for?

Comment: It seems the UK has the concept of [escorts](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/escort)? 3.a. "a person, esp a young woman, who may be hired to accompany another for entertainment, etc" [or here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/escort#cald4-1-2-1) "someone who is paid to go out to social events with another person, and sometimes to have sex"

Comment: @Mitsuko I don't think the role of 芸者 is found anywhere else exactly than in Japanese culture. So you'll have to understand that other cultures might have something nearby but not capturing all the features of 芸者. To that end, what features are most important? The entertainment (music)? The personal conversation/attention? Being paid to do all this? In English (and European) culture personal attention and being paid almost necessarily means prostitute, which is not always implied by 芸者.

Comment: @shoover : I assumed that such a profession existed in Britain in the past (e.g. a couple of centuries ago). This is why I used the past tense in my question. I meant the time period during which the profession existed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no British equivalent to geisha. 'Polite' social gatherings in the past would have been for gentlemen *and* ladies; they might have included performances by professional musicians etc, but these people would not have been expected also to entertain in other ways. All-male gatherings might have invited 'ladies of easy virtue', which is why many British people assume that geisha were equivalent to prostitutes.